# Publishing a Silverlight with reference to a WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I created a RoleService in my silverlight project and through that got hold of the embership/Role functionality. I am running this on a local machine and is wondering how to publish this to my website. I have 3 web applications:

1. My main web application where the silverlight object shoule be merged into
2. The silverlight project which lets me develop the silverlight application
3. The silverlight host application which I use for testing

In the web application (1) i have made the RoleService so that i can get a hold on my Roles. In the Silverlight application (2) I have a service reference to the service mentioned above which I consume and loads my Role data. This howecer doesnt work when i publich it online. But how do i get it to work online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because it is trying to connect to service with wrong address? If so, then you just need to propagate WCF service address to your Silverlight application through hosting web.config and start connecting to a correct service.

Let me know if this is the case, then I will share exact solution for this.

Comment: I never got it to work, i suspect that its the issue you describe that im having problems with. I didnt want to spend much more time solving this so i chose to make a hidden field on the page where i wrote role name in and then accessed the hidden field from my silverlight, not so pretty - but its working.